# How to run Django at a local machine after deploying it to DigitalOcean apps

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean

I'm using Digital Ocean app platform to host my website but after following the settings from the end of [this documentation](https://docs.digitalocean.com/tutorials/app-deploy-django-app/) from the website (at the end of step 2), there's something I think I'm missing because I have deployed the app following the guide but now I can't run it on my local machine.

The error comes from this snippet, throwing the Exception "DATABASE_URL environment variable not defined"

```
elif len(sys.argv) > 0 and sys.argv[1] != 'collectstatic':
    if os.getenv("DATABASE_URL", None) is None:
        raise Exception("DATABASE_URL environment variable not defined")
    DATABASES = {
        "default": dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")),
    }
```

I thought I should use something like python-dotenv or django-dotenv or having multiple Django settings modules, but my brain right now is just frosted.

Comment: What local operating system are you running? Do you have the `DATABASE_URL` env var set? What database system are you using - MySQL?

Comment: I mean... you'd need to set that environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `python-dotenv`, check the docs: https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/
and dj_database_url to connect to your database through HTTP using the url, check the docs: https://pypi.org/project/dj-database-url/#description

To set environmental variables:

1. create a **.env** file in your root directory
2. declare the variables`: name = value

```js
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    import dj_database_url

    #your django settings.py

    load_dotenv()

    DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.parse(
      os.getenv("YOUR_DB_URL")
    )
```